# How to register truffle contract with ENS(Ethereum Name Service)?

Tags: truffle, ens, embark

I am wondering how I can publish my smart contract to ENS via truffle. I think I might need to include a smart contract called `ENS.sol`, but I am not sure.

Is it the same as publishing a package to [ethpm](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/package-management-via-ethpm), do I use truffle publish?

Does truffle have build in ENS support like [Embark](https://out.reddit.com/t3_9jdghu?url=https%3A%2F%2Four.status.im%2Fembark-3-2-much-more-than-a-moonshot%2F&token=AQAA-cOvW_KdBrNftqdTt1QhnNDMJhhTgk6ryvfKGmRcwV1c_owu&app_name=desktop2x&user_id=63651606).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by publishing a contract to ENS. Some things you might want to do with ENS: have your contract own a name in ENS, be able to query ENS from within your contract, or have your ENS name resolve to the contract address.

Comment: Ya that sounds more accurate, contract own a name in ENS, or ENS name resolve to contract address, thanks for clarification :)